# Mysql index comparison to mysql query

Tags: mysql, search, indexing

I've such a question about mysql indexes. I know that index is used to speed up searching, but is the difference between this situations ? => let's bring some example. first => mysql query `"SELECT name FROM BIO WHERE LIMIT 0,100"` and second => (let's consider that dx is index of name column) mysql query `SELECT dx FROM BIO LIMIT 0,100`
I think that in that situations there is no difference and want to hear from you guys your opinions :)
Correctly I should written in second example like so yes `"SELECT name FROM BIO LIMIT 0,100"` ? 
I've made some changing in examples to express data searching speed
I don't know indexes well and because of it I'm asking ...
Thanks ...

To say more correctly what I want to understand that is the difference between (created index column "name") index and searching data only with name (like "`SELECT name FROM ...`") ?

Comment: I think it will not make any diff because search does not run on indexed field.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about, but you may check "Index-covered query"

Comment: Handler-socket is another topic you may be interested in

Answer (score 0):

You know, that you should index the id-column to speed up both of your given queries? If you have done that, there should be no difference because of the selected columns. And if the id-column is an integer datatype please drop the quotes so MySQL has no hard time transforming the datatype of the where clause.

```
SELECT name FROM BIO WHERE id=2;
SELECT dx FROM BIO WHERE id=2
```

Comment: yeah, I guess about datatype :)

Comment: To be true, nobody here knows, what you want. Again: In your given examples an indexing of the selected columns is not necessary for speeding up the query!

Comment: thanks man , I wanted to hear that , was it necessary in this situation creating index or not :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only retrieve the value of the indexed column in the select clause (and don't use MIN() or MAX() on that column), but don't use that column anywhere else, then an index doesn't make your query faster:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html